# multiple network adapters in virtual machines

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, hyper-v

I need to set up server infrastructure for a client with 20 virtual machines. There will be two SQL Clusters and other machines will be web servers and active directory.

I have been suggested to use separate network adapters for the type of communication i.e. one for active directory communication, other for SQL (only in web and SQL servers) and another for web servers to communicate with load balancer.

I need your advise if this is the right way to do it or should I use only one network adapter?

Comment: You haven't provided enough detail or context for us to tell if this is in fact sound guidance, but on the surface I'd say that it isn't very sound guidance. Who's telling you this?

Comment: This might be more sound guidance in some physical infastructures. Do the various resources exist on diffrent subnets? Virtual network adapters will scale and so the most common use case is to prevent routing when dealing with multiple subnets. In terms of physical adapters on the clusters it's better to aggrigate and then set limits or reservations then try and manage something very dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for simple traditional networking boundaires then trunk the physical switch ports, use VLANs, and tag the vNICs of the VMs.

If you're looking for performance management, then look at the QoS functionality available to you in Hyper-V.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with multiple NICs and have them LAG or/and for fault tolerance if needed. I didn't understand if you ask about physical or virtual NICs.